# When will GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged Event raise

Tags: asp.net, gridview

When do **GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged** Event raise?

How " **GridView1.SelectedDataKey** " capture the value?

Comment: I assume that you've read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx). _"Occurs when a row's Select button is clicked, but after the GridView control handles the select operation."_ What was unclear?

Answer (score 0):

GridView.SelectedIndexChanged Event Occurs when a row's Select button is clicked, but after the GridView control handles the select operation.
and if you want to find selected  value then you need to use Gridview's DataKeys property, like GridView1.DataKeys["your_SelectedDataKey_index"]["your_selected_row_index"]. This is a read only property.

Answer (score 0):

In MSDN it has been explained very well.

1. [GridView.SelectedIndexChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
2. [GridView.SelectedDataKey Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selecteddatakey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Moreover

[Getting DataKey from GridView on Edit and Delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808104/asp-net-getting-datakey-from-gridview-on-edit-and-delete)